# LIBGDX FreeTypeFontGenerator - Crash on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, truetype

I have been trying to add in .ttf fonts to my android mobile application. I am using the Libgdx engine to create my application, and have tried to add in the True Type extension to allow the use of .ttf fonts. Here is the code that I am running to try and create a font.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/font.ttf"));
BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(12);
generator.dispose();
```

When I call this code, my application gives me the `Unfortunately, X has stopped.` message and no other information. I have included the `gdx-freetype-sources.jar` and the `gdx-freetype.jar` in both the core and android projects. I have clicked the option to export them on both projects. And I have included the two `libgdx-freetype.so` files in the `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` folders.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Edit: Here is my error output code in the 'LogCat'

```
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 7533
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195): Process: com.zach.nice, PID: 31195
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$Glyph.id
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.generateData(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:288)
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.generateFont(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:137)
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.generateFont(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:148)
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at com.zach.nice.Nice.create(Nice.java:53)
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:292)
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
04-19 15:33:08.479: E/AndroidRuntime(31195):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: probably this is the solution for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19953410/2399024

Comment: Could you give me the link for the latest version of the Libgdx-setup-ui? I thought the one I downloaded was the most recent version, but I guess I was wrong.

Edit: I tried updating my core and android projects, and I tried running it again. But it did not change anything.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to use the last nightly build instead of the release build of libgdx. The version of Libgdx setup ui shouldn't matter, because as I remember it is downloading latest versions of libgdx when you set up or refresh a project.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem .
The latest freetypefont builds are using a newer version of the libgdx that have some huge changes .The addition of the id field in the Glyph class is one of them. All you have to do is update all the libgdx jars in your project to the newer ones.

Here is [the link for the latest build](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/libgdx-0.9.9.zip)

Probably you will have to do some changes in your code too cause alot have changed to the libgdx lately